# How to make a decahedron

Tags: javascript, html, geometry, shapes

Hi I've found some code that animates 3d shapes and even gives an example of making and animating an icosahedron I'm trying to turn it in to a decahedron though and my geometry is pretty bad. The code I have for the icosahedron is:

`// draw a icosahedron`

```
    var tau = 1.6180,

    phi = 20.90515745,  // (180-138.1896851)/2

    rt3 = Math.sqrt(3),

    d = sideLen/2,

    foldTbl = [ 60, -60, 60, -60,
                   -60, -60, 60,  60,
                    60, -60, 60, -60,
                   -60, -60, 60,  60,
                    60, -60, 60, -60],

    moveTbl = [  0, 2*d,  0, 2*d,
                   2*d, 2*d,  0,   0,
                     0, 2*d,  0, 2*d,
                   2*d, 2*d,  0,   0,
                     0, 2*d,  0, 2*d],
    triangle = ['M',0,0,0, 'L', d*rt3,d,0, 0,2*d,0, 'z'],
    tri,
    faces = g.createGroup3D(),
    bend = -2*phi,
    i;

for (i=0; i<20; i++)
{
  // create the next face
  tri = g.compileShape3D(triangle, "red", null, 1);  // backColor irrelevant
  faces.addObj(tri);
  faces.translate(0, -moveTbl[i], 0);
  faces.rotate(0, 0, 1, foldTbl[i]);
  faces.rotate(0, 1, 0, bend);
  faces.translate(0, moveTbl[i], 0);
}
return faces;
```

i'm sure there must be an easy way to make this a decahedron but if anyone has any advice that'd be amazing - thanks!

Comment: Which [kind of decahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decahedron) are you referring to? Or do you mean a dodecahedron?

Comment: Well it was going to be a decahedron but struggling to find any on decahedrons I've opted for a dodecahedron. I think i've found a site that might help: polyhedra.org I can't use WebGL unfortunately as it needs to work on mobile devices and IE. There's a heap of resources for WebGL too so it's a shame.

Comment: Decahedron has to be a typo.  That's why you found no info on it.  There is no regular polyhedron having 10 faces.  If you want a smooth ball covered in regular pentagons, that's a dodecahedron (12 faces).

Comment: Nope afraid not a decahedron is a 10 faced polyhedron. A 10 sided dice is a good example - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decahedron

Answer (score 1):

If you have coordinates for an icosahedron but want to draw a dodecahedron, you can make use of the duality between those two. Take the icosahedron, and put a new vertex in the middle of every one of its triangular faces. Connect two new vertices with an edge if the corresponding faces of the icosahedron had an edge in common. You will obtain a dodecahedron, with one vertex for every face of the icosahedron, and one face for every vertex.

Comment: awesome thanks. I'll see if I can give that a go. My geometry's awful but i'll see if  I can make sense of it :)